# Speed issues with VPN to cooperate network in Europe from Asia - is it possible to attach a local VPN server to the europe network?

Tags: network, vpn

Got this situation where we are forced due to security reasons to only be allowed to connect through VPN to our network - which is fine when you are in Germany (GER) where the main office is located, and absolutely horrible when you are located at the branch office in the Phillipines (PH) due to really slow connection to Europe from there.

We wont allow people to go directly on the internet without going through the internal security measures thats setup on the company network.

What i was thinking but simply havent been able to find any answers to if it this model would be able to work :

The idea is that we setup a local VPN server in PH that we connect to - this server is 100% managed by the German IT department, they setup whats allowed on this machine and what is not but it would give us the benfit that it would then be able to use the local internet instead of having to channel all traffic back and forth to germany.

Since we also besides internet traffic would require to access the company network there should be a link from this VPN server to the main office network in germany ( a secondary VPN ) and im thinking there could be set up some routing tables or something between the two to direct traffic between them ?

Would this be possible at all and would it be OK from security perspective if the machine is absolutely locked down to only allow Germany to adminster it ? wouldnt the only safety issue then be if someone physically broke into the machine ?

It should route internal network traffic, ex if we want to access a shared drive on the network across the tunnel between germany network and our local vpn server, but internet traffic it should channel through the local internet line ?

Is this possible at all or am i totally on the wrong end here ? and if its possible whats something like this called ?

[image]

Comment: What you're suggesting is technically possible. I don't know if it's politically feasible in your company.

Comment: okay do that 'model' have a name of the technique ? its impossible to find any information out there where someone done it or uses it so i worry if theres a big catch to doing it this way ?

Comment: @vidarlo if the local VPN server is protected hard like fort knox or something, then i cant spot the big security issue - as long as its impossible locally to adminster the server and only from Germany.

Comment: You'd stil need a secure environment in which to house the servers... and it would have a cost.

Comment: @vidarlo cost as in money doesnt matter - the main issue is the speed problem since traffic the current way always get transported across the german vpn and back and it kills the speed for any public cloud based stuff ( on the internet ) but still there are rules to which things to allow to connect to so we cant just fully open the internet locally - has to go through a controlling unit which i were thinking could be the VPN.

Comment: it's still a policy issue. If someone wants to do it, it's readily doable. Spend your time on documenting the problem, to convince the company.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is definitely possible and is likely a good solution to your problem, assuming it is set up properly. Firewall rules and routing should solve most of the usability and security issues.

I don't think there is a particular name for this, as it is still just a VPN configuration. Maybe [split tunnelling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling) works to describe it?

Comment: if OP's main interest is to have normal internet fast, shouldn't it also be possible to just locally split what goes via the VPN and what doesn't? Depending on company size and affected people working from whatever other country, this might be more viable than setting up local VPN hosts in all countries.

Answer (score 1):

> We wont allow people to go directly on the internet without going through **the internal security measures** thats setup on the company network.

It is unclear what these internal security measures are, which means that one cannot say if they can be replicated in the setup you envision. For example it is not uncommon to have a deeper inspection for web traffic which includes SSL interception and virus scanning. The simple VPN server you envision will not be able to do this since this is far more than just VPN.

Which does not mean that a more scalable setup with a **local internet breakout** is impossible. Several vendors offer their enterprise firewall products as cloud instances so that one could not only create a simple VPN server in the cloud but also a fully featured analysis system. Vendors like ZScaler take this one step further and provide all the infrastructure and managed security already, so mobile clients or branch offices can just connect to an existing service instance with fast connections to the user or office.

But going this way means that **companies have to rethink how their security works**. It is not as simple as just putting some new virtual machine somewhere in the cloud. There are new risks (but also new chances) one has to consider since essentially the company is giving up some control: a bit if the analysis is hosted as virtual machine in someone's else cloud and a lot if it uses not only outside managed infrastructure but also outside managed security. Thus, don't expect that your management will happily and quickly implement your idea since the technical implementation is only a small part of what needs to be done.

Comment: regarding the security measures i am not 100% sure all thats covered here, but i think there antivirus software installed and that they monitor all the traffic that goes across the line also manages white and black lists. The idea with a server locall was that they could replicate if any anti virus software and have their white/black lists running there too. I dont know in detail about vpn's but its possible to setup the routing in the vpn server itself so it could route some traffic directly on local line instead of tunneling all up & down the vpn between the endpoint ?

Comment: @MdTp: like I said, it is possible to run a setup like this but it is not as simple as duplicating the current setup somewhere in the cloud. It comes with its own new risks. It also needs some central management of policies with decentralized enforcement of policies on multiple places - which makes designing and managing such system more complex compared to having only a single point of inspection.